# South Korea navigation app

Tags: driving, south-korea, mobile-apps, gps-navigation

I'll be in South Korea for a couple of weeks and would love to rent a car there to drive around the country. What is the best navigation app I can use there(with English interface of course)? It seems like GMpas is completely useless, it can't make any driving routes.

Comment: OT: I see that the online [Google Maps](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@36.464873,127.2983145,7.5z) camera cars have been active in South Korea, around the urban areas, and they show many other roads. Perhaps the app is good for you.

Comment: For background info, [this article](https://timzertravels.com/why-doesnt-google-maps-work-in-south-korea/) seems to explain the situation as of 2022, and why Google Maps doesn't work (South Korean law bans the storage of data about South Korea on servers outside SK); it recommends an app called Naver but I can't vouch for it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naver Map and KakaoMap both have an English version.  They are the most commonly used navigation apps by locals. I believe Waze and GMaps also work from what I recall driving there a few years ago.

FYI: [Android or iOS navigation app that gives an alert when close to a speed camera in South Korea](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/30864/903)